Keydown functions and screen readers
I have a script whereby if a user is focused on an element and presses the down arrow key, it expands/collapses a section. Works in all browsers I've tested without a screen reader, and it works on Safari with VoiceOver on. But as soon as you turn JAWS or NVDA on it stops working. Here's the script:
$(".axxs-accordion .a-trigger").keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next(".a-section.collapsed").focus();
    }
  }); 

And the HTML:
<div class="axxs-accordion">
  <h2 class="a-trigger" tabindex="0">Heading</h2>
  <div class="a-section collapsed">
    Content here
  </div>
</div>

So it seems that JAWS and NVDA hijack the arrow keys. Any ideas?
Edit - here is a test link:
AXXS Accordion

I haven't worked with screen readers before. Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76605486/trap-arrow-key-navigation-on-modal-using-screen-readers and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922495/navigating-with-arrow-down-key-on-first-li-tag-in-ul-doesnt-work-when-using-nvd

Thanks @dula that first link does touch on the issue, but the way I read it, it says the solution is to add a tabindex to the element. Mine already has that, and it still doesn't work. Hmmm.

Can you give a link to a test page ? However, additionally to what I have already explained in the other question, simply using tab/shift+tab to navigate doesn't necessarily implies that form/focus/application cursor is automatically activated. Note also that arrow keys aren't standard keys to expand/collapse sections, except in tree views or combo boxes, so if you aren't in such a case, you should rather prefer enter/space.

Added the accessibility tag, as the question is related to screen readers. I found this question thank to the link you posted in comments on the other question, otherwise I would have missed it completely.

@QuentinC test link added above. It works perfectly in Safari/VO, but not other screenreaders. The philosophy is that screen reader users should not have to expand sections to read content. It's dumb when they can already navigate by heading, etc.

You say that screen reader users shouldn't need to open/collapse sections. Why not, this isn't a bad reasoning and it can simplify the life of screen reader users, but then it makes something inconsistent. Assume down arrow works as you intended. I'm a Jaws user, pressing down arrow doesn't appear to do anything for me as I always see everything. So why this heading should be focusable as it does nothing ? You see where  I'm going, you can't have something focusable for one category of users (keyboard users) but not another one (screen reader users).

I was afraid of this - a philosophical argument on why/why not I shouldn't do this. So let me preface this by stating that I am a Certified Professional in Web Accessibility by the IAAP with 10 years of experience. But for your edification - screen reader users don't need to expand/collapse sections because they can navigate by heading. Making them click useless buttons is unnecessary work.

I am a Certified Professional in Web Accessibility by the IAAP with 10 years of experience ==> Some people are so called certified experts and it didn't prevent them at all from saying big b..sh..t. This isn't your case here, but I have already seen it and so I'm always questionnning and/or suspicious. I have updated my answer and now you have the technical explanation why your code doesn't work, and as well I think quite a good idea of how you could maybe make it better.

Short answer
You must add a proper role to make the element fully functional with screen readers and the keyboard.
Making an element focusable with tabindex=0 isn't enough to make it fully functional with screen readers and the keyboard, as pressing a certain key produces different effects depending on the role.
The effect of arrow keys is especially sensitive, as they are among the most important keys of the keyboard. You must pick a role corresponding to something normally focusable, and appropriate with the function of the element, such as button or link for example.
Detailed answer
Arrow keys aren't working when your heading has focus because, from the screen reader perspective, what your focusable heading does when it has focus isn't well defined, and hance the screen reader doesn't well know how it should behave.
Making the element focusable with tabindex=0 isn't enough to make it fully functional on the keyboard. You also need to give it a proper role.
You need to give it a role of something that can normally take focus, such as button, link, textbox, listbox, combobox, etc. and which most accurately represent the foction of the element.
Here, the most appropriate role for something that opens/collapses a section would certainly be button, although activating a button is normally done with space or enter rather than down arrow. This is something you should reconsider if you opt for the button role, as the keyboard and/or screen reader user expects to activate it with enter or space and will not understand that it works with down arrow if you don't explain it somewhere. In fact, as you will understand further below, down arrow won't work any better with the button role, as down arrow isn't supposed to do something special on a button. You will need to change for enter/space or take another (probably less appropriate) role.
Depending on the configuration of the screen reader and the role of the element, the screen reader behaves differently upon pressing arrow keys.
For example, with automatic cursor management, pressing down arrow inside a button simply leaves the button, switch from form/focus/application cursor to virtual/document/browse cursor, and goes to the next line of text, while pressing down arrow on a multiline text box can go to the next line of text within the text box (without leaving it nor switching to the virtual/document/browse cursor).
Similarly, if a button, link or form element is encountered when pressing down arrow when the virtual/document/browse cursor is active, the form/focus/application cursor is turned on and the system focus is placed on the element, allowing the user to interact with the element seemlessly without thinking a lot about which cursor is or should be active.
The current role by default of your element is heading, and this is normally not an element that should receive focus.
Hence the screen reader doesn't know what it can/should do.
Both Jaws and NVDA seem to agree to don't turn on form/focus/application cursor automatically when encountering your focusable heading, whether you reach it with tab or arrow keys.
Since form/focus/application cursor isn't turned on, the down arrow press isn't transmitted at all to your script. It performs the navigation function of the screen reader instead, i.e. go to and read the next line of text.
VoiceOver seems to have made the opposite choice, it consider the element to be something like a sort of undefined form element and don't expect a particular role to be specified. It turns the equivalent of the form/focus/application cursor on, it puts the system focus on the element, and transmit keyboard events.
It would be interesting to compare if the behavior of VoiceOver is the same if you navigate with tab or with VO+left/right or sweep left/Right on mobile.
Now if you force turn on form/focus/application cursor on, by pressing Insert+Space with NVDA, or by disabling virtual cursor in Jaws, keyboard events are successfully transmitted to your element, and down arrow works as you intended.
But this is not natural to do so for the screen reader user. Nothing is announced when reaching the element, and no one will have the idea to do it unless it is known in advance.
To wrap up, you should add a role like button to make it fully functional. And not only you must give a proper role, you must also handle keyboard events as the user expects it for that role.
In theory, if you could, you should use the appropriate element such as <button> for the button role. By the first rule of ARIA (don't use it unless you really need to), it's much better to use the correct element from the start rather than changing the role of an element.
However, in your particular case, if you write <h2 role="button">, then you lose the heading role and the heading is no longer available when navigating by heading (with H key) or browsing the heading list. Oddly enough, writing <button><h2>...</h2></button> as the theory would recommend it also does the same. So you must be very careful on what elements and roles you use to keep heading navigation / heading list working.
<detail>/<summary> would be even better for a collapsable section as it works out of the box without any script, but headings aren't allowed inside <summary>. So not a good idea in your particular case
About making accordion always only useful to sighted people
I'm a screen reader user myself, so I can only applause  your reflection saying that the accordion is useless for blind users and that the content always appear open for us. It's much simpler, and after all you are right, accordion is often just a visual thing we shouldn't care about as blind people.
However, it forces you to make something slightly inconsistent, or to accept a compromise because there is no perfect solution.
As explained above, the down arrow key won't work without an appropriate role, and by overriding the role of the element, you may break the normal heading navigation provided by screen readers.
So my final suggestion after explanations  in your comments would be to leave as it is, don't make any change. It won't work with Jaws and NVDA, and nothing will announce the feature, but after all it doesn't matter, since for a blind person, it doesn't do anything useful anyway.
We are just left with a totally useless tab stop for those who use a screen reader and navigate with tab rather than arrow keys or heading navigation. Not perfect, a little questionnable, but acceptable. It isn't a big deal and it allows keyboard only users without screen reader to use your site perfectly.
However, it's getting  tricky if you consider that blind people aren't the only people using a screen reader. Partially sighted people, and those with dyslexia and other dys troubles do can also use screen readers. ANd for them, your simplification for blind users who can totally ignore the accordion is strange: the screen reader reads text which is maybe not on screen. Confusing, right?
Users who are sighted, using a screen reader and navigate with the keyboard only, all that in the same time, are blocked, as they can't expand the hidden content although it is perfectly read by the screen reader. A lot more confusing! But as I explained in the first part, fixing it for them will cause problems for blind users. So, again, no perfect solution.
As a blind user myself, I will obviously advise the solution which doesn't break things for us. But that's a compromise. Statistically speaking, to my knowledge, the vaste majority of Jaws and NVDA users are blind. Partially sighted users combine them with magnifiers like ZoomText, and as far as I know, dys people use completely other software more tailored to their specific needs. Maybe you should test with these other softwares and maybe it works without changing your code.

There are so many things wrong with this answer I don't know where to begin... Summary elements have numerous problems, like they can't contain headings. Buttons within headings cause problems because when a screen reader user navigated by heading it announces "heading button collapsed", but when they press the enter key nothing happens, because it's not actually focused on the button. Traditional accordions suck, and VO is the only screen reader who handles my improved version properly. I'm trying to get the other ones to behave.

Let me add a question to my last comment to clarify: if there were no script and no styles attached to my page, how would a screen reader navigate it? By using headings and arrow keys. That's how this should work as well. Accordions are purely so sighted users don't have to read through a bunch on non-pertinent information to read what they want.

Buttons within headings cause problems because when a screen reader user navigated by heading it announces "heading button collapsed", but when they press the enter key nothing happens, because it's not actually focused on the button. ==> For me with Jaws it works correctly, but there's another problem, the heading inside the button doesn't appear in the heading list, nor it is reached when pressing H. At the end it makes navigation worse.
So I will update my answer, thank you for pointing that out.

Summary elements can't contain headings. ==> I also overlooked this one, so again I will remove that advice, as it makes no sense in your particular case. Thank you again.

Answer updated to take your last comments into account

This must be the accepted answer, it's perfect.

Thank you for the clarifications and the answer, as well as adding the fact that you are a blind screen reader user, because that is very helpful. My apologies if I came across as rude. I tested a previous version of this out with other blind users and they said they thought it was great. What I am trying to do is make something with zero issues for everyone. And when I said it was a tricky question, I meant it :) If I remove one thing it will fix everything for blind users, but break it for sighted keyboard users.

@AndréPolykanine - no, it's not. What QuentinC probably didn't realize when testing it is that one of the accordion sections contains a link which is accessible to everyone except blind NVDA and JAWS users.

@DeanH: Indeed, I haven't noticed the link. I managed to make it appear once but I don't understand how exactly. I'm trying again with no luck. Strange! What have you done to this link?  In any case it's certainly another unrelated problem, and another question.

It looks like the down arrow key still goes through sometimes, and make the link appear. I'm beginning to understand what you have tried to do. So that's another inconsistency for your concept. But this one is really problematic, unless you restrict yourself to not put any link or focusable element inside the collapsible/expandable content.

@QuentinC - it's not an inconsistency, it's intentional. If the link were focusable all the time, a sighted keyboard user could tab inside of a closed section and lose focus. That's a WCAG violation, and it would be annoying. That's why it's rendered inert until the section receives focus. If you're interested in helping out more with this and other components, email me: dean at axxs dot io
I would love some input from an actual screen reader user.

it's not an inconsistency, it's intentional. If the link were focusable all the time, a sighted keyboard user could tab inside of a closed section and lose focus.  ==> I had well understood. But by doing so your link isn't accessible to screen reader users and they can't open the collapsed section reliably (they don't even know that it's expandable). At the end your whole thing is broken for one kind of user or another and there is no working solution for everybody in all cases, that's why I call that inconsistent.

As I have said, as a blind, I can only applause the idea of removing the need to expand sections. But as you can see, in practice, it creates other problems or restrictions, and there is no obvious solution that could work for all. So this isn't a viable concept, sadly.
